# Un endpont me genera "RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop" al usarolo dos veces seguidas. Flask Matplotlib Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, flask, machine-learning

estoy haciendo una API REST con flask para generar un reporte en PDF con los datos extraídos de un dataset(.csv) al momento de aplicar machine learning, al probar la ruta me funciona perfecto, me genera el pdf con las gráficas y la información, pero al volver a acceder al endpoint me dice **"RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop"**, vi que ya habían preguntado sobre este error pero las respuestas y el contexto no tienen nada que ver con lo que me pasa a mi (creo).

Este es el endpoint, quité las validaciones para que no se vea tan extenso.

```
@cross_origin
@csv_report.route('/generate_report', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def generate_report_csv():
    path_temp = './src/temp/'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            file = request.files['wine_red']

            new_filename = _filetools.generate_file_hash(file.filename)
            save_temp = os.path.join(path_temp, new_filename)
            file.save(save_temp)
            wine_data = pd.read_csv(save_temp,
                                    sep=';', engine='python',
                                    skiprows=0, index_col=False)

            boxplot_routes = []
            for col in category_cols:
                boxplot_routes.append(boxplot_graph(wine_data, col))

            wine_data.dropna(inplace=True)
            wine_data.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

            bargraph_routes = []

            for col in category_cols:
                bargraph_routes.append(bar_diagram_graph(col, wine_data))

            wine_data['quality'] = wine_data['quality'].apply(
                lambda x: 1 if x > 6.5 else 0)

            X = wine_data.iloc[:, :-1].values
            y = wine_data.iloc[:, -1].values

            X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = (
                train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42))

            sc = StandardScaler() # <- instanciado fuera del endpoint

            # aplicar escalado estandar
            X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
            X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test)

            clf.fit(X_train, y_train) # <- instanciado fuera del endpoint
            y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

            conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
            precision = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
            f1_score = metrics.f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')
            roc_score = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)
            recall_score = metrics.recall_score(
                y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')

            tree_img = tree_graph(wine_data)
            first_for_box = boxplot_routes[:4]
            second_for_box = boxplot_routes[4:6]

            first_for_bar = bargraph_routes[:2]
            second_for_bar = [bargraph_routes[2],
                              bargraph_routes[4], bargraph_routes[5]]

            generate_pdf(first_for_box, second_for_box, first_for_bar,
                         second_for_bar, conf_matrix, precision, f1_score,
                         roc_score, recall_score)

            return jsonify({'message': 'Report generated successfully'})
        except Exception as ex:
            return jsonify({'error': str(ex)})
```

Los métodos boxplot_graph, bar_diagram_graph, tree_graph retornan gráficas en forma de imagen para ser usadas en el PDF, los tres son básicamente esto:

```
def save_img(name: str) -> str:
    file_name = ''+_filetools.generate_file_hash(name.replace(' ', ''))
    plt.savefig(_path_img+file_name)
    return str(_path_img+file_name+'.png')


def boxplot_graph(data_frame, column: str) -> str:
    sns.boxplot(data=data_frame[column], orient='h')
    plt.title(column)
    return save_img('boxplot-'+str(column))
```

Reitero, mi problema es que al usar el endpoint una vez encendido el servidor local funciona perfectamente, pero al volver a hacer la petición para generar otro PDF me arroja el error **"RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop"**, no es hasta que reinicio el servidor que se soluciona...

Answer (score 0):

No puedo meter esta respuesta como comentario pero ahí te va,

En caso de que todaviá no lo hayas solucionado, tal parece que tiene que ver con matplotlib este problema, es cuestión de configurar el uso de matplotlib de esta manera

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Yo estoy teniendo el mismo problema pero en mi caso para hacer pruebas tengo el matplotlib pero probablemente pueda eliminarlo de mi codigo, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).